# What is the right way to get the list of DNS servers responsible for certain host?

Tags: dns, cname

I use following steps:

1. Query A records for host, some servers return NS records in authority section, so I extract them from that section, if any.
2. Query NS records, extract them from answer section.

The problem is with "subdomains" (CNAME), for example:

`> dig www.microsoft.com A`

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.microsoft.com.      696     IN      CNAME   toggle.www.ms.akadns.net.
toggle.www.ms.akadns.net. 119   IN      CNAME   g.www.ms.akadns.net.
g.www.ms.akadns.net.    263     IN      CNAME   lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.
lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.  31      IN      A       65.55.12.249
```

`> dig www.microsoft.com NS`

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.microsoft.com.      619     IN      CNAME   toggle.www.ms.akadns.net.
toggle.www.ms.akadns.net. 42    IN      CNAME   g.www.ms.akadns.net.
g.www.ms.akadns.net.    186     IN      CNAME   lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
akadns.net.             174     IN      SOA     internal.akadns.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1304057105 90000 90000 90000 180
```

`> dig lb1.www.ms.akadns.net A`

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.  79      IN      A       65.55.12.249
```

`> dig lb1.www.ms.akadns.net NS`

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
akadns.net.             176     IN      SOA     internal.akadns.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1304057402 90000 90000 90000 180
```

As you can see, there are no NS records returned. How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong.  Here's the right one.

For each successively shorter superdomain `S` of the target domain name `T`, starting with `T` itself:

1. Perform an `NS` lookup on `S`.  If the answer is not a non-empty resource record set, go to step 3.  Otherwise you have a set of intermediate domain names `D[]`.
2. Perform `A` and `AAAA` lookups on each name in `D[]`.  This will give you a set of IP addresses.  You have your answer.  **END**.
3. Optionally perform a `SOA` lookup on `S`.  If the answer is a non-empty resource record set, you are about to cross an administrative boundary having found no non-empty `NS` resource record set thus far.  You may choose, according to exactly what you are trying to find out, to **ABEND**.

Remember that you have to make queries to your own [resolving proxy DNS server](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html#ResolvingProxy), not to the external content DNS servers, so that you get a [complete answer](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-response-taxonomy.html#Complete) rather than a partial one.  Also remember that you have to follow `CNAME` chains when inspecting responses.  The response to your `dig www.microsoft.com. NS` query above, for example, is a `CNAME` chain leading to an *empty* `NS` resource record set for `lb1.www.ms.akadns.net.`.

Comment: Thanks! Already adopted similar algorithm, but now I know how to do it right.